# Charge distribution in electron

Tags: electrons, charge

In the Wikipedia article [Classical electron radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius#Derivation) in calculation of radius of electron. Charge distribution of electron described as $$\rho(r)= \frac{q}{4{\pi}Rr^2}$$for $r\leq R$. This is variable density why it is not constant like volume charge density $\frac{3q}{4{\pi}R^3}$ I know this will change the value of radius but my question is how such charge distribution is concluded for electron.

Answer (score 3):

There are currently three derivations in that article: for a sphere of constant charge density, for a spherical shell of charge, and for the charge distribution you give.  The difference is the numerical factor $f$ in the electrostatic energy $E=f\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{ r_e}$ (which is 3/5, 1/2, and 1 for the three example charge distributions).

That particular charge distribution is a terrible choice since it suggests a rigorous process was used to come up with a "model classical electron" with $f=1$.  The logic goes the other direction.  The relationship
$$
m_\text ec^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{r_\text e} = \frac{\alpha\hbar c}{r_\text e}
$$
is chosen purely by [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis); the only reason to consider a uniform sphere or a spherical shell of charge is to confirm the bias that the dimensional result is correct to within a factor of about two.  Since there are not any features of the electron interaction that change at femtometer-ish length scales, it doesn't make sense to say that the electron has a "classical" radius at all, and the factor of two is moot.

I note that the article has been "flagged as having multiple issues" for seven years. Maybe one of us should clean it up.